# Create Responsive Content Slider

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, slideshow

I did search for two days for responsive slide but didnt find so I need help.
I do not want jquery plugin, but simple jquery code so it will be light.
So here is slideshow code:

```
<div class="slidebox">
    <div class-"slide">Slide 1</div>
    <div class-"slide">Slide 2</div>
    <div class-"slide">Slide 3</div>
</div>
```

So now I will need jquery code to slide left or up each slides.
Some plugins did this job but need to be set box width, but I want to all box width auto, so if PC screen width will be less it will not effect it.
Thank you.

Comment: That is html code, where is the jQuery code you tried?

Comment: Something similar that I want is this plugin http://css-tricks.com/examples/StartStopSlider/ But it use fix width.

Comment: Simple solution is this script: http://jsfiddle.net/nsjithin/5f8dM/ But I want to remove buttons from it. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, so in my case I prefer to use some plugin for a specific task, for example a slider.
I recomend you for example Flexslider, it is easy and clean, of course responsive  http://flexslider.woothemes.com/

Good luck !